# My Honda Accord is overheating

Tags: honda, accord, overheating, coolant-leak

I have a Honda Accord 1992, coolant was leaking and I saw the temperature goes up,   the radiator was old and I replaced but the coolant is boiling I do not know what to do next, please I need help.

Comment: What coolant did you use to refill? Was it a 50/50 mix of distilled water to antifreeze?

Comment: It's less expensive to start with the thermostat

Comment: Along with the obvious proper coolant and the thermostat, a cooling system pressure test, including the cap, would be a good idea. If the system is unable to maintain pressure, it will overheat no matter what coolant you have in it.

Comment: What climate are you in?  Is it below freezing?

Comment: Although I am currently in the process of figuring this out myself, just for giggles take off the radiator cap and let the vehicle idle for a bit. If my guess is correct, you will no longer experience the overheating and boiling coolant.